# Cannot import pyautogui because 'Source code cannot contain null bytes.'

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to use pyautogui to get a screen shot but upon simply saying import pyautogui, Visual Studio Code immediately informs me that it can't due to "Syntax error, 'source code cannot contain null bytes.'"  When I run the program the console says the same.  When I attempt to uninstall and reinstall pyautogui using py -m pip uninstall pyautogui I get an error, "ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path".  I don't truly understand what this null character is or where it is or how to remove it.  If anyone has any ideas on how I could make pyautogui usable again I would greatly appreciate it.  I don't believe the problem is in my code but I'll show it anyways in case it'll get help faster.

```
import pyautogui
import numpy as np
import cv2

while True:
    im = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (170, 425, 900, 515))
    print("working")
    img_np = np.array(im)
    cv2.imshow('Video', img_np)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: null character is `0x00`

Comment: The file`pyautogui.py` that you are trying to import is clearly corrupted. Look for every file on your system called `pyautogui.py` and open each one in a text editor. You will soon see if there is one that doesn't have something like Python code in it. Delete it when you find it. It is probable that you accidentally typed `somecommand > pyautogui.py` (or something equivalent) at some point. Reinstalling won't help because the file causing the problem isn't in your `python3x\lib` directory but more likely in your working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely dealing with a corrupted file. The easiest remedy is reinstallation (use `pip uninstall` then reinstall), but this won't work if the corruption is in your working directory. Your next step is to manually check each file on your system (which shouldn't be *too* many) with pyautogui in the name and see if any of them contain something other than python code. If you find a file that does, delete it and then reinstall.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the files in `python36_64\lib\site-packages` folder corrupted to all hell and manually removed the entire pyautogui package.  This solved the corruption to the files and I can now uninstall and reinstall the package with ease.  However, I am now getting another null bytes error when running my original program:  ```in <module>
    import pygetwindow
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes```.  I don't know if this is related to the original problem so I'll leave it here in case.

Comment: Nevermind, in the same folder I found the pygetwindow package and found __init__.py was also corrupted and simply copy pasted from the pygetwindow github.  Works beautifully now.